# Sound dies. How to get it working again without rebooting?

Tags: audio, kernel-modules

My sound subsystem dies irregularly. It can be fixed by rebooting, but I am wondering if I can fix it simply by restarting it - thus avoiding the reboot.

I have tried:

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

That does not fix the problem.

Then I tried unloading the modules (to reload them later):

```
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_codec_hdmi
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_codec_analog
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_codec_generic
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_controller
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_codec
sudo modprobe -r snd_hwdep
sudo modprobe -r snd_pcm
sudo modprobe -r snd_seq_midi
sudo modprobe -r snd_seq_midi_event
sudo modprobe -r snd_rawmidi
sudo modprobe -r snd_seq
sudo modprobe -r snd_seq_device
sudo modprobe -r snd_timer
sudo modprobe -r snd
sudo modprobe -r soundcore
```

All of these give:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module XX is in use.
```

As some of them depend on eachother it makes sense for some of them, but not for this one:

```
$ lsmod |grep hdmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
```

Then I tried forcing the removal:

```
$ sudo rmmod --force snd_hda_codec_hdmi
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'snd_hda_codec_hdmi': Resource temporarily unavailable
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module snd_hda_codec_hdmi: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`fuser -v /dev/snd/*` returns nothing, so it does not seem there is a process accessing the sound subsystem.

Versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hp 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa \n \l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/sound-reload fixes it for me every time.